# Is injective function $f:A \to A$ always surjective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Ok so while browsing a book(namely Herbert Endertons book "Elements of set theory") I have stumbled upon a curiosity which provoked me to try to prove this.Here is how I went about it,but I do not think my solution is correct.

All answers as well as corrections are more then welcome.

Proof:

Since $f: A\to A$ and f is injective we have $$(x,y)\in f \implies x \in A  \;\;\land \;\; y\in A \implies (y,z)\in f \;\; \land \;\; z\neq x $$

by using this step repeatedly,we will eventually exhaust set A of members,and thus range is equal to domain.

However I am not sure that I have covered a case where there is element which is in relation with x.Also I am not sure what would happen if the domain and range are set of real numbers(as I have only managed to study up to natural numbers so far).

All input is highly appreciated

Comment: If $A$ is infinite it might not be the case that you "exhaust the elements of $A$". For finite sets it is true.

Comment: Have you considered $f(x)=2x$ where A is the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Do you have suggestion which would help prove this statement for infinite sets?

Comment: What is $A$?${}{}{}$

Comment: @VanioBegic: It is not true for infinite sets.

Comment: Vanio, the statement is *false* for infinite sets. So the only suggestion I can come up with is not to try and prove it. But at the same time, try and prove it, and see where you feel that you're "skipping". Then get back to the definitions (e.g. the definition of infinite sets) and see why you couldn't bridge the gap.

Comment: Would you elaborate as I am not on good terms with infinite sets,so to speak

Comment: @VanioBegic Consider the injective map $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ that maps $n\to 2n$.

Comment: @VanioBegic I gave you a counterexample.

Comment: Asaf Karagila thanks for suggestion,but I have only studied the book up to and including properties of natural numbers,I have not embarked upon infinite sets.If you could elaborate in a full answer I would accept it as correct

Comment: Vanio, if you haven't studied infinite sets, then perhaps it's best to postpone this discussion until after you've learned about them.

Comment: @Thomas I promise I didn't copy Grumpy's example in my comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You statement works for finite $A$. If 
$$
f: A\to A
$$
is injective then it is surjective.

This is not true when $A$ is infinite. Consider for example the funcstion $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x) = 2x$. This function is injective, but not surjective,

Comment: Thank you very much,topic closed

Comment: Sorry,I thought I did already